# Outlook/gmail Configuration not working in Swiftmailer's smtp?

Tags: emails

I have been using **Swift Mailer** for sending mail. I have also installed the dependency module and library.

Now, I have been trying to configure the gmail/outlook configuration for Transport Type **SMTP** in swift mailer.

```
Gmail :

   Server: smtp.gmail.com
   Port: 465
   Encryption: Use SSL

Outlook :

  Server: smtp.office365.com
   Port: 587
   Encryption: Use TLS
```

Error is showing like,

> An attempt to send an e-mail message failed.
>
> Unable to send email. Contact the site administrator if the problem
>   persists.

and showing message in green like

> An attempt has been made to send an e-mail to (Email ID of
>   gmail/outlook).

Note: Enabled **Allow Less Secure Apps Access** in gmail settings and these configuration are all trying in my local instance.

How could I solve this ?

Comment: have you typed in the account username / email and password in SwiftMail's smtp settings form?